# 'groups' vs 'groupent' - can't copy into directory despite group membership

Tags: ubuntu, file-copy, group

Can someone please explain why the following happens?

```
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ whoami
lloydb
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ getent group vboxusers
vboxusers:x:127:lloydb
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ ls -ld testfile VirtualMachines/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lloydb lloydb       5 Jul  6 11:57 testfile
drwxrwxr-x 3 root   vboxusers 4096 Jul  6 12:21 VirtualMachines/
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ cat testfile 
test
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ cp testfile VirtualMachines/
cp: cannot create regular file 'VirtualMachines/testfile': Permission denied
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ sudo chown lloydb VirtualMachines/
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ ls -ld VirtualMachines/
drwxrwxr-x 3 lloydb vboxusers 4096 Jul  6 12:21 VirtualMachines/
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ cp testfile VirtualMachines/
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ ls VirtualMachines/
lost+found  testfile
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$
```

That is:

- Clearly I'm in the vboxusers group. (I'm the local user, not on a
  network or ssh connection, and I've logged out completely from the
  GUI then logged back in.)
- But that's not sufficient to let me copy a file into VirtualMachines/
  even though that directory has rwx permissions for the vboxusers
  group.
- It's only when I'm the actual owner of VirtualMachines/ that I'm
  allowed to copy anything into it.

Might it be related to the following?

```
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$ groups
lloydb adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
lloydb@lloydb-ASUS-z390-A:~$
```

That is, `getent` shows I'm in the vboxusers group but `groups` suggests I'm not. TIA.

Comment: Are you still logged in to the same session during which you added yourself to the `vboxusers` group?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply John. No I'm not. Perhaps I should have been clearer but that's what I meant by "(... logged out completely ... then logged back in.)" Also I'd have thought that a logout/in issue would have affected what "getent group" showed anyway.
<Edit: Give me 2m and I'll even reboot to make absolutely sure. />

Comment: The `getent group` command just looks at the PAM source (in this case, the `/etc/groups` file). It doesn't consult the information in the running session. That's the most common situation when I've seen this sort of discrepancy, which is why I asked. The next thing I can think of to check would be ACLs on the `VirtualMachines/` directory, though I'm not sure that would be applicable here either...

Comment: Thanks John, I'll check those.

Comment: Whoa, now I'm really confused: ```groups``` didn't show me as a member of vboxusers after I'd logged out then back in (see proof above), but it does after I've rebooted. My guess is the file copy may work now - I'll check - but obviously this seems to raise a new question.

Comment: Yep, that's fixed it. So my original file-copy question was a red herring: The real question is why logging out then back in wasn't sufficient to change my group membership; I had to completely reboot the machine.